# Running Knative serving e2e tests locally

Tags: knative-serving

I am trying to run the serving e2e tests locally using kind.
These are the steps I have followed:

1. kind create cluster
2. Install Knative serving using the steps from here: https://github.com/knative/serving/blob/main/DEVELOPMENT.md#starting-knative-serving
3. ko apply -f test/config
4. go test -v -tags=e2e -count=1 ./test/e2e

I observe multiple test failures related to webhook like below:

```
autoscale_test.go:108: Failed to create initial Service: autoscale-sustaining-aggregation-linear-lvfacqoc: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.serving.knative.dev": Post https://webhook.knative-serving.svc:443/?timeout=10s: dial tcp 10.99.61.94:443: connect: connection refused
```

Am I missing any other important steps?  How do the Knative developers run their e2e tests in general?

PS: I am using the latest main branch (Release v0.24.0)